# How to make a multi-user file server system with PHP?

Tags: php, permissions

I'm just looking a big picture idea here; I can google specifics once provided with guidelines.

I want to make a relatively simple file hosting website such as dropbox or skydrive for mainly pedagogical reasons.

Making a multi-user login and registration system with PHP and MySQL is pretty straight forward, but how would I go about managing file directories and permissions for each user?

Comment: This question is far too broad.  Please have a look at the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for ideas on how to formulate your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At its simplest: Store files somewhere in any hierarchy you want in a location that's not simply publicly accessible through the web server. Store meta information about each file in a database. In said database, store who the owner of the file is. Write a script that allows people to download those files (see [`readfile`](http://php.net/readfile)), require that users are logged in and that only owners of files can them.

Comment: So you're suggesting to store permissions data for each file in a database. The PHP function readfile seems like something I would be using. I also looked at LDAP was wondering if that was something I could potentially use?

Comment: Maybe, but seems overkill unless you're using LDAP anywhere else. The specifics of how the access control is implemented depends on what exactly you want. Group-accessible files? Single-user only? Temporary access? You can model whatever you need on top of your database structure.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably hundreds of ways to do this, but this is what I would do:

- They should never have a direct download path as it can be abused.
- All files could be stored in the same place.
- File names should be changed to unique ids to avoid dupilcates.
- Store the file name, unique id, and user id in a database.
- When they visit the page for the unique id, you can do your checks and display the file info.
- You will then pass the file to them rather than having them download it directly.
- Their user page would show file names and links to those pages, etc.

I hope that is a good jumping off point.